# WPF application template not available in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have just installed Visual Studio 2010.

when I attempt to create a new project in c#, there is no option for a WPF application. There is for Visual Basic.

The WPFApplicaton.zip flie does exist in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I propose that this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129992/wpf-application-template-is-missing/5720578#5720578  There are additional answers there. Hope you were able to resolve the issue anyway... that problem is pretty annoying when it happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to run the installer again - it should come up with "repair" and "change" (or something like that) options along with "uninstall".

"Repair" will reset what you already have installed.

"Change" (or "Update" - I don't have VS2010 installed on this machine to check the actual wording) should let you run through the install again adding and removing components. Step through this double checking that you've installed all the templates and options.

If that doesn't work then you could try an uninstall and re-install/

Comment: Thanks. Really should've tried that before coming here...sorry.
(That's the problem with SO, it's too good for it's own sake.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the targeting .NET framework.

Select File menu from VS2008 or VS2010; Select .NET framework 3.5 or 4.0; Select Visual C#. you will find WPF Application template listed