# WPF Application template is missing

Tags: wpf

My VS2010 install has WPF Browser application project template, and WPF User Control lib template, but no WPF Application template. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar problem here: my VS2010 (SP1) has the "WPF Application" project template, but neither WPF User Control Library nor any other WPF project templates.

Answer (score 7):

For me I was missing ProjectTypeGuids in the .csproj file (a new project worked for me so just compared the project files), so if you add this to the .csproj file under PropertyGroup I then had all the WPF types available for adding:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this has solved the issue for me. I had a few "PropertyGroup" elements, so I just selected the one that is configured for debugging.

Comment: This worked for me!  I had a "Project ToolsVersion="12.0"" C# WPF app in a VS 2015 ("VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28010.2003") Solution, that would only list one ("User Control (WPF)") of 8 normal WPF Item Templates (from at least VS 2015 and 2017 albeit in VS 2015, it would also list 3 MVVM Light Templates and VS 2015 was the only of the 2 that had that Extension), even though other C# WPF Projects and enclosing Solutions older and newer worked fine.  Why would it not have the `ProjectTypeGuids`?!  I'm pretty sure I didn't intentionally remove it, I doubt I accidentally did.

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of an old question, but I just hit the same issue and found the answer after the above didn't help, so....the solution for me was that I had to select a higher framework version (4.0) before the WPF Application template I was looking for became visible. If you find that you don't have the WPF or other project templates you expect available, you may want to check that you've selected the approriate framework version from the drop-down list immediately to the right of the "Recent Templates" label in the Add New Project dialog (it's near the top-left of the dialog in question).

Comment: I ran into the same thing. Doh!

Comment: Good catch, I forgot I set the framework version to the lowest (to see how long I can go with .NET 2.0) long times ago.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is a lot older than Visual Studio 2010. It goes back to 2005 at least. Lucky you, I was missing the New Class template once.

According to a bunch of sources, this trick works:
**If you are missing a template that comes with your installation, run devenv.exe with the /installvstemplates switch.**

You'll need to exit out of all Visual Studio instances for this to work.

The trick is mentioned in the MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx

Thread on the issue in a previous version of Visual Studio: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/8a5ae9e3-be7b-493d-831c-1e49e8103f26/

I wound up uninstalling and reinstalling my Visual Studio entirely but this trick probably would have fixed my problem.

Comment: Warnung

This switch is supported only for Visual Studio partner development, and is not available in Express editions. You must run devenv as an administrator in order to use the /Setup (devenv.exe) and /InstallVSTemplates (devenv.exe) switches. For more information, see User Permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Just had this in VS2017 Community Edition. This discreet message to add missing templates helped me:

[image: Add templates]

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 5 (or newer) is needed to have in .csproj in xml path Project/PropertyGroup:

```
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017
Make sure that you have .Net Desktop Tools checked in you VS

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44429/missing-wpf.html