# How does one start a WPF Project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm struggling with something very fundamental - so I'm probably being dumb.

I'm following the [MSDN Tutorials for learning Visual C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/jj153219) and one of the very first things you do (following changing the theme color, of course) is create a new project. **The project template(s) listed, specifically "WPF Application", are not existing, however.**

Here's what the tutorial says I should see:
[image: MSDN Tutorial's view]

The same process is used by [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/getting-started/hello-wpf/).

What I see lacks "WPF Application"
[image: My view]

Uhh.... what? When I use the search box for "WPF", I find "WPF App for MVVMbasics Core project" which I have to download from online, but get this error message when using it:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you tried re-installing VS?

Comment: perhaps helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129992/wpf-application-template-is-missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The give away is in the title of the dialog box displayed when you try to open a WPF project (my emphasis):

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express **for Web**

The Express products each only support a subset of the project types. Choose "Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" from the [Visual Studio Express page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx). Alternatively, if you meet the "Who can use Visual Studio Community" requirements at the bottom of the page, you could download [Visual Studio 2013 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs).

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing from .Net Framework 4.5 to 4.0 or 3.5 from the comboBox above.
If that solves, then you may need to install .Net Framework 4.5 on your system.

And if not, run the Visual Studio Installer again. Will be better to remove and install again than just using 'Repair' option in the installer.

Select 'Full' option on components selection if it asks for while installing..

Reinstallation would defenitely help. But if you don't like to spend that much time.. Take a look at
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a5ae9e3-be7b-493d-831c-1e49e8103f26/visual-studio-project-templates-are-missing?forum=vssetup